# Handle nil in loop from list Golang

Tags: loops, go, runtime-error

I'm looping through some data received from a backend and might contain a nil in the middle, the program crashes with `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

How can i handle the nil? Would like to set an nil to show "EMPTY"

I've tried this but still crashes:

```
    for _, res := range resp.Autombiles {
        for _, trk := range res.Trucks {
                if trk == nil {
                    println("EMPTY")
                } else {
                    println(*trk.EngineType)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my loop:

```
    for _, res := range resp.Autombiles {
        for _, trk := range res.Trucks {
                fmt.Println(*trk.EngineType)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if trk == nil` ...?

Comment: @mkrieger1 edited my question on what i tried, not be getting it wrong.

Comment: `EngineType` is a pointer field and its `nil` even when `trk` isn't. So you need to check both against `nil` if you want to dereference the `trk.EngineType` field, i.e. `if trk == nil || trk.EngineType == nil { print(empty) }`.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks this works now, how do i factor in an else print *trk.EngineType in the above code.

Comment: @mkopriva ```if trk == nil || trk.EngineType == nil { println("empty") } fmt.Println(*trk.EngineType }``` gives same error.

Comment: Either do the dereferencing in an `else` block, or add a `continue` statement to the `if` block. Of course it gives you the same error if you ignore the fact that a pointer is `nil` and you attempt to dereference it anyway. `println("empty")` will not magically ignore the rest of the loop's body by itself and do the next iteration or exit. `println` just prints, that's all. *You* need to tell the program to do the right thing. Right now, you're telling it to dereference a nil pointer, which, anytime you do that, *will* cause the "invalid memory address or **nil pointer dereference**" `panic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `res.Trucks` is nil. So your program crashes before `trk` variable is created, here. `for _, res := range res.Trucks{}`

```
for _, res := range resp.Autombiles {

    //       res.Trucks can be nil
    for _, trk := range res.Trucks {
            ...
    }
}
```

So, add a check for existance of `res.Trucks`

```
for _, res := range resp.Autombiles {
    if res.Trucks != nil {
        for _, trk := range res.Trucks {
            if trk == nil || trk.EngineType == nil {
                println("EMPTY")
            } else {
                println(*trk.EngineType)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EngineType is also a pointer field so we need to check if trk and trk.EngineType == nil ```if trk == nil || trk.EngineType == nil { println("EMPTY") }```